# Why security group in inbound rules from another vpc instance not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have two ec2 instances from different vpc's, and I need to add to inbound rules of first instance security group of another, but because they from different vpc's aws not allow this(only IP). But I used [this article](https://medium.com/faun/deep-dive-into-aws-vpc-and-vpc-peering-3ea919bd367a) to setup peer connection and route tables to be able use security group in inbound rules even for instances from different vpc. And it worked before, but some time ago we found that our server can't connect to db. Error is:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myrdsaddress.amazonaws.com' (110 "Connection timed out")
```

But when I change in inbound rules of my rds rule from security group to IP it's start working again. So my question is how I can returns back to using security group in inbound rules? IP is not the solution because it's changing every time we deploy new build.

Comment: If you're trying to access db from the vpc that doesn't have an internet connection through the second vpc it won't work. Please check this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/invalid-peering-configurations.html Otherwise, it worth checking the actual request path with VPC flow logs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html

Comment: Did you add a public or private IP to get it to work again?  And does `myrdsaddress.amazonaws.com` resolve to a public or private IP address?